# Change video start playing time inside a composition - After Effects

Tags: after-effects, compositing

Here is screenshot of my projects.
[image]

- **Pre-comp 1** is made with inerted shapes
- **phoneFooting_New.mp4** is a **8 second**s video
- **Red Solid 1 Comp1** is a composition made with :
  [image]

  - A **36 seconds** video called **iphoneNavigation.mo**v and
  - **Red Solid 1**

**iphoneNavigation.mov** starts playing at *0s*. I want it, to start playing at *24s* instead. Please how can I perfom that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you automatically trim a new layer in After Effects?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13081/how-can-you-automatically-trim-a-new-layer-in-after-effects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drag the footage to the left, until the point you want is aligned with the start, or you can type in an exact number in the **In** column in the timeline window. By default this column is not shown, to show it right-click in the column headings, where it says **Source name … Parent & Link** and select **In** from the list.

[image]

You can click the number and enter `-24.` in the text field. **Pro tip:**you don't have to type the zeroes, AE will add them for you if you type `.`, this works for hours and minutes too, so if you wanted 1:02:00 you could just type `1.2..`

[image]

This brings me to the third way to do it. In the current time box, type `-24.` to set the current time to -24, then hit <kbd>[</kbd> to set the layer's in point to the current time (the comp window will be grey because you're outside the composition). Hit <kbd>home</kbd> to go back to the start of the comp.

[image]